# Multi-room chat logging in Rails/MySQL app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I'm coding a browser game application in Rails. It's chat-based, and I'm using currently MySQL for the databases. However, I'm running into a problem when it comes to chat logging for the games.

The application goals dictate that there will be multiple rooms at any given time in which people are playing the chat-based game. Conversation will be pretty much constant, and there are a number of other actions, such as private messages and game actions, which must be logged as well. Players who join the game after other players must be able to see the chat log from before they joined, and games must be available to review.

My first thought was to, on game start, create a database that matches the game identifier, and store everything there. Then when someone joins the game, we could just parse it back to them. Once the game had been over for a certain time, the script would take the database content, parse it into an XML object, and store this in a dataase for game review, deleting the table to keep things running lean.

I created a moddel called Message, with a matching table with identical columns for those I want to store in the game tables - id, timestamp, sender, target (for PMs and actions), type of message and content. Then I set the initializer for the Message object to set the table name to 'game_#{game_id}'. Rails however is throwing tantrums - I get an undefined method has_key? error when I try to initialize the object in Rails. It occurs to me based on this that the method I'm using may be a bit un-Rails-ian, and that possibly it defeats the purpose of working in Rails to pass up using the excellent object/db management features it has.

I've considered other alternatives, such as temporarily keeping all the messages in the main Messages table and just querying them by game ID, but I'm unsure if a MySQL table is up to the task of speedily serving up this data while accepting constant writes, especially in the event that we get a dozen or more games going at once averaging a message or two per second. It was suggested to me that a noSQL solution like a MongoDB capped collection for the temporary storage would be an excellent option from a performance standpoint, but that would still waste all that ActiveRecord goodness that Rails offers.

Is there a reliable and relatively fast way to meet the constraints of making the logged messages able to be quickly stored and fetched for quick access while the game is ongoing and then stored in some type of low-overhead method for review? Would any of the above ideas be workable or is there a whole separate option I've overlooked?